# Zend - Generate Speaking URL from Modulel/Controller/View Logic

Tags: zend-framework, seo, routes

with Zend you can add routes for better URLs, e.g. like this:

```
$oRouter->addRoute( 'imprintRoute', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static( 'imprint/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'imprint', 'action' => 'index') );
```

Is it possible to get the correct URL in a reversed way, e.g. when I use the module/controller/action logic in my template?

```
<a href="{$this->url(['module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'imprint', 'action' => 'index'])}">Imprint</a>
```

should be printed as example.com/imprint/

Do you have any ideas or examples?

Kind regards,
netzaffin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url()` method takes four arguments:

- **array $urlOptions** Options passed to the assemble method of the Route object.
- **mixed $name** The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route
- **bool $reset** Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided
- **bool $encode** Whether or not to encode

So you can add your route name as a second argument as follows:

```
<a href="{$this->url(['module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'imprint', 'action' => 'index'], 'imprintRoute', true)}">Imprint</a>
```